# does brownian motion and poisson random measure have to be independent?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose a brownian motion $W$ and a poisson random measure $\mu$ are defined on the same filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, (\mathcal{F}_t), P)$, where both $W$ and $\mu$ are $\mathcal{F}_t)$ adapted. Then does it have to be the case that $W$ is independent of $\mu$? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are independent; for a proof see e.g.

N. Ikeda, S. Watanabe: *Stochastic Differential Equations and Diffusion Processes*, Theorem II.6.3.

Note that a similar question (for the case of Poisson processes, not Poisson random measures) has been discussed on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57808/correlated-brownian-motion-and-poisson-process).

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I want!

Comment: But are you sure it's theorem I.6.3. in Ikeda and Watanabe's book? I just checked the book, and it turns out that theorem I.6.3. is not about Brownian motion and poisson random measure.

Comment: @Sean Sorry, it's II.6.3

Comment: I found it, thank you!